# Getting System.InvalidOperation exception while trying to execute command line script using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, system.diagnostics, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to execute a command to generate PDF file using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).

If I execute following command using command prompt, everything works fine.

> `C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin\phantomjs.exe C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\rasterize.js http://localhost:9992/index.html outputFile.pdf A4 landscape 0.1in`

If I try to execute the same using C#, I see

> System.InvalidOperation exception.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
var url = "http://localhost:9992/index.html"
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false ; 
startInfo.FileName = "C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin\phantomjs.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

startInfo.Arguments = @"/c /K C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\rasterize.js " + url + "C:\temp\output.pdf A4 landscape 0.1in";

try
{
    // Start the process with the info we specified.
    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch
{
    // Log error.
}
```

See the below image for inspector when debugging.

[image]

Comment: Why do you launch `cmd.exe` why not set `startInfo.FileName = "C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin\phantomjs.exe";` then do `startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\rasterize.js " + url + " output.pdf A4 landscape 0.1in"`

Comment: You may want to log the output too so you can see what's going on. Take a look at some other process launcher implementations to see how to do that, e.g. https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/02c29d2d2732df8bfe746661b9f1392583628d57/src/Cake.Core/IO/ProcessRunner.cs

Comment: If you want to use cmd.exe do not forget to add /C in front of your arguments otherwise the cmd.exe will run without expecting any argument and will close immediately

Comment: Also, your code says your variable is named `exeProcess` but your screenshot says it is named `proc`, are you sure you are looking at the correct object?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I was trying lot of things, I think i changed the variable name & then i took the screenshot.

Comment: Also, if your process has already closed, the debugger information isn't going to be of much use. The `InvalidOperationException` shown likely isn't the problem, it probably just means there is no process remaining.

Comment: @Steve: do you mean something like this: `startInfo.Arguments = @"/c  C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin\phantomjs.exe C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\rasterize.js " + url + " output.pdf A4 landscape 0.1in";`

Comment: Exactly or /K to leave the cmd.exe window open and see if you get any error message telling you more about your problem

Comment: @Steve: Thank you for quick reply. I tried adding both `/K` & `/c` options but I do not see command window. I have changed `startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;`

Comment: Have you tried not using `cmd.exe` and just launching the program like I mentioned in the first comment?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That helped. I am able to get rid of exception. I initially tried this option  & it did not worked may be because, I did not specific full path. I was relying on `PATH` variable. or may be some other issue. But I am still not able to get the desired result. I do not see any exception and there are no errors.

Comment: Update your question with the updated code, and also provide a detailed explaination about what "it did not work" means, does it run but `output.pdf` not show up? If so, where are you checking for the file? have you tried putting a full path for the output? maybe it is just being saved somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thank you for quick reply. I have updated the question. By its not working I meant `I am not seeing output.pdf file`. I tried looking inside the bin folder of the application & after specifying the full path, I checked the other location as well but no luck

Comment: You still have `/c /K ` in your arguments, you should not be using them if you are not calling `cmd.exe` Also your question says you still get `InvalidOperationException`, however that is not the problem anymore.

Comment: You might want to tag this with the `phantomjs` tag instead of `InvalidOperationException`. There are 496 followers of the tag `phantomjs`, but 0 followers of `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: THANK YOU for your help. I have posted an answer based on your help. Even though I am getting desired result I have two questions. `1.` if i use quick watch after this line `using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))`, I still see some of the properties throwing invalid operation exception. `2.` How I can tell command line to put the file in bin folder of the application, instead of specifying file using `c:...`

Comment: 1) I don't know why you can't look at them. I would try to get the data out in code, catch the exception, and look at the exception details for more info about why they are invalid operation exceptions.2) Set the working directory of `startInfo`, note if this program gets "installed" and is put in to the "ProgramFiles" folder you can't write to the directory the program is run from.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thank you for explanation. I am not getting any exceptions unless, i use quick watch over process object. Currently system is using following directory by default to put the files. `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`

Comment: being that you are using IIS, you should really be telling it to save the file in some path defined by calling [`startInfo.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Pdfs")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx), this will set the working directory to the `~/Pdfs` folder relative to your website.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
var url = "http://localhost:9992/index.html"
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false ; // This must be false to use env variable
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin\phantomjs.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

startInfo.Arguments = @" C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\rasterize.js " + url + @" C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\output.pdf A4 landscape 0.1in";

try
{
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch
{
    // Log error.
}
```